# Bitbucket cannot checkout repository in Sourcetree

Tags: git, repository, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I recently changed my password and cannot checkout my Bitbucket repo in Sourcetree. I keep getting the following error:

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false -c credential.helper=sourcetree fetch origin 
fatal: remote error: CAPTCHA required
Your Bitbucket account has been locked. To unlock it and log in again you must
solve a CAPTCHA. This is typically caused by too many attempts to login with an
incorrect password. The account lock prevents your SCM client from accessing
Bitbucket and its mirrors until it is solved, even if you enter your password
correctly.

If you are currently logged in to Bitbucket via a browser you may need to
logout and then log back in in order to solve the CAPTCHA.
```

Repository:

```
https://testuser.com/bitbucket/repo.git
```

I logged in and out many times, solved the CAPTCHAS and still get the same error. Do I need to update something on Bitbucket side? Sourcetree side? Or maybe a URL?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by setting up SSH for Git by following these steps:
https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-ssh-for-git-728138079.html

Repository:

```
ssh://git@testuser:repo.git
```

Previously I was using HTTPS protocol and it was causing errors.

Answer (score 3):

on macOS, this has worked for me:

1. Close SourceTree
2. Open Keychain Access
3. Search for "bitbucket" and remove any entries
4. Go to bitbucket website, log-out and login again
5. Open SourceTree and enter your password